# move / copy mass number of products to other categories

Tags: magento-1.9

I have a large number products that I need to move or copy to other categories in Magento 1.9.1.1.  How is this possible?

Is this also possible through database? If it is, which table(s) should modified?

Answer (score -1):

Try this, Before that **take a Backup**

You can achieve this easily ***using a MySQL query.***

As per as my suggestion this is the best way.

Magento saves product-category associations in the ***catalog_category_product***  table.

### Steps

**Step 1:** Take a backup of the database. Mainly the ***catalog_category_product*** table.

**Step 2:**  Run the below query for *moving products from the old category to the new category*.

> SELECT {NEW_CAT_ID} cat, `product_id`, `position` FROM
>   catalog_category_product WHERE `category_id`= {OLD_CAT_ID} AND
>   product_id NOT IN (
>       SELECT `product_id`
>       FROM catalog_category_product
>       WHERE category_id = {NEW_CAT_ID}));

Suppose, your ***new category id is 7***, and ***the old category id is 4***.

```
INSERT INTO catalog_category_product(

    SELECT 7 cat, `product_id`, `position`
    FROM catalog_category_product
    WHERE `category_id` = 4
    AND product_id NOT IN
    (
        SELECT  `product_id`
        FROM catalog_category_product
        WHERE category_id = 7
    )
);
```

**Step 3:** Delete records from the old category using a MySQL query:

> Delete from catalog_category_product where category_id={OLD_CAT_ID};

**Example:**

```
Delete from catalog_category_product where category_id=4;
```